# Read large message file (*.msg) stuck in HornetQ

Tags: jboss, hornetq

I am working on a app which has a lot of asynchronous messages hosted by HornetQ 2.3.21. By some process my message size goes more than 2GB and the message starts failing with this message on the server:

```
HQ212017: error adding packet: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Maximum size of 2gb exceeded
   at org.jboss.netty.buffer.DynamicChannelBuffer.ensureWritableBytes(DynamicChannelBuffer.java:82) [netty-3.6.9.Final-redhat-1.jar:3.6.9.Final-redhat-1]
   at org.jboss.netty.buffer.DynamicChannelBuffer.writeByte(DynamicChannelBuffer.java:205) [netty-3.6.9.Final-redhat-1.jar:3.6.9.Final-redhat-1]
   at org.hornetq.core.buffers.impl.ChannelBufferWrapper.writeByte(ChannelBufferWrapper.java:539) [hornetq-commons-2.3.21.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.3.21.Final-redhat-1]
   at org.hornetq.core.buffers.impl.ResetLimitWrappedHornetQBuffer.writeByte(ResetLimitWrappedHornetQBuffer.java:249) [hornetq-core-client-2.3.21.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.3.21.Final-redhat-1]
   at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientLargeMessageImpl$HornetQOutputStream.write(ClientLargeMessageImpl.java:205) [hornetq-core-client-2.3.21.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.3.21.Final-redhat-1]
   at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:116) [rt.jar:1.8.0_251]
   at org.hornetq.utils.InflaterWriter.doWrite(InflaterWriter.java:106) [hornetq-core-client-2.3.21.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.3.21.Final-redhat-1]
   at org.hornetq.utils.InflaterWriter.write(InflaterWriter.java:63) [hornetq-core-client-2.3.21.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.3.21.Final-redhat-1]
   at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:116) [rt.jar:1.8.0_251]
   at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:75) [rt.jar:1.8.0_251]
   at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.LargeMessageControllerImpl.addPacket(LargeMessageControllerImpl.java:185) [hornetq-core-client-2.3.21.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.3.21.Final-redhat-1]
   at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl.handleLargeMessageContinuation(ClientConsumerImpl.java:748) [hornetq-core-client-2.3.21.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.3.21.Final-redhat-1]
   at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientSessionImpl.handleReceiveContinuation(ClientSessionImpl.java:935) [hornetq-core-client-2.3.21.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.3.21.Final-redhat-1]
   at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientSessionPacketHandler.handlePacket(ClientSessionPacketHandler.java:65) [hornetq-core-client-2.3.21.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.3.21.Final-redhat-1]
   at org.hornetq.core.protocol.core.impl.ChannelImpl.handlePacket(ChannelImpl.java:641) [hornetq-core-client-2.3.21.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.3.21.Final-redhat-1]
   at org.hornetq.core.protocol.core.impl.RemotingConnectionImpl.doBufferReceived(RemotingConnectionImpl.java:557) [hornetq-core-client-2.3.21.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.3.21.Final-redhat-1]
   at org.hornetq.core.protocol.core.impl.RemotingConnectionImpl.bufferReceived(RemotingConnectionImpl.java:533) [hornetq-core-client-2.3.21.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.3.21.Final-redhat-1]
   at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl$DelegatingBufferHandler.bufferReceived(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:1693) [hornetq-core-client-2.3.21.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.3.21.Final-redhat-1]
   at org.hornetq.core.remoting.impl.invm.InVMConnection$1.run(InVMConnection.java:165) [hornetq-server-2.3.21.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.3.21.Final-redhat-1]
   at org.hornetq.utils.OrderedExecutorFactory$OrderedExecutor$1.run(OrderedExecutorFactory.java:105) [hornetq-core-client-2.3.21.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.3.21.Final-redhat-1]
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [rt.jar:1.8.0_251]
```

This message is stored on the filesystem in the `messaginglargemessages` folder.

I want to read the message to see which process is causing the issue, but the message is encoded in a binary format. How can I read this file? I tried some utilities available on Internet to convert `.msg` files, also changed the encoding, also tried sending this message to code which reads binary files but no luck. I am not sure the contents of message will be human readable or not. We need to get the module name which should be part of this message. Once we get the module name we might find some other solutions for 2GB error.

The operating system is Windows but we see the same messages and issues on Linux as well.

Comment: I have .msg file which is not readable. I want to make it readable. Can you suggest any way by which I can read this .msg file so that I would know whats the request causing this issue.

Comment: yes, its not readable. This message are located in "messaginglargemessages" folder, this message are called as message journal. The operating system is windows but we see the same messages and issues on linux as well.

Comment: Its not human readable. I tried all the easy ways to decrypt the message but no luck.

Comment: Horntq version is hornetq-2.3.21. I am getting Maximum size exceeded message on server. I tried some utilities available on Internet to convert .msg files, also changed the encoding, also tried sending this message to code which reads binary files but no luck.

Comment: On the environment only info logging is enabled. We need to get the module name which should be part of this message once we get the module name we might find some other solutions for 2GB error. yes I am aware about hornetq transition. We have used hornetq very readily and upgrading will be a very big task.

Comment: I am not sure the contents of message will be readable or not.But if you can just tell me couple of things which I can try to decode this .msg file? That will be a great help sir!

Comment: I am getting the error and stacktrace with message Maximum size of 2gb exceeded. but the stacktrace is all around Jboss classes which is not that help full for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221964/discussion-between-ayush-somani-and-justin-bertram).

Comment: I am getting this message in my server logs and I am not sure this is on sender side or receiver side. That I will now by reading this message

Comment: The stack-trace indicates that it's on the receiver's side. Can you confirm? Are you embedding your broker in the same JVM as the clients? The use of `InVMConnection` indicates that you are. Can you confirm?

Comment: I am not 100% sure but I too think so because the sender and reciever code executes on the same jvm machine that is the server JVM.

Comment: @JustinBertram Do you know any configuration by which we can increase the upper cap size of large message to any size more than 2GB?

Comment: This looks like an internal issue between the broker and Netty. My recommendation would be to move to ActiveMQ Artemis.