# JBoss HornetQ/ActiveMQ Artemis saving queue message to file system

Tags: jboss, activemq-artemis, hornetq

Can someone please help me in understanding the impact of saving Hornetq/ActiveMQ Artemis messages to the file system and bypassing the queue every time?

The message is more than 2GB, and I run into `Maximum size 2GB exceeded` exception in HornetQ [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64025468/read-large-message-file-msg-stuck-in-hornetq). So I was planning to not add the message to queue but write it manually to disk and pass the path of the file in header and read the message from the file. I really don't know the performance impact so asking if I do for all messages less than 2GB, will there be any performance impact?

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking. HornetQ and ActiveMQ Artemis are message brokers. If you send a durable/persistent message to the broker it will be stored in a queue and written to disk. What do you mean "bypassing from Queue everytime"?

Comment: The message is more than 2GB's and I run into Maximum size 2GB exceeded exception in hornetQ. So I was planning to not add the message to Queue but write it manually to disk and pass the path of file in header and read the message from the file. I really don't know the impact so asking If I do for all messages less than 2GB, will there be any impact?

Comment: What broker are you actually using? HornetQ or ActiveMQ Artemis?

Comment: Also, what exactly do you mean by "will there by any impact"? That question is really vague. What kind of "impact" are you talking about?

Comment: Using HornetQ for now and migrating to ActiveMQ Artemis,  Impact as in there should be some performance impact saving to filesystem manually and not passing the message to Queue. Do you have some insights to this?

Comment: Have you reproduced this issue using ActiveMQ Artemis?

Answer (score 1):

Given the information you've provided I don't think anybody but you can determine the "performance impact" of manually writing the file to disk vs. sending the file to the broker.

Generally speaking, you will save the time required to send the file to the broker in the first place, but you don't indicate how fast the hard-drives are. If the hard-drive on the broker is much faster than the hard-drive on the client then it may take longer overall to write the file to disk manually.

Also, if the network is slow between the clients and the broker and fast between the clients and the shared drive where you're going to write the file then it may be overall faster to write the file to disk manually.

Ultimately it's going to be up to you to test the performance impact of your changes.